# How to decide which column has more weightage to output

Tags: data-preprocessing, data-science, feature-selection, data-labelling

[image: Column_A and Column_B is input columns]

As per Image we can see Column_A value is directly proportional to output,

While Change in value of Column_B has no effects in output.

So basically I want to know is there any algorithm where I can get weightage of columns which is affecting more to output than another.

In this case we can see Column_A has more weightage as change in Column_A value will lead to change in value of B.
but in case of Column_B it will be no change.

Expected Output:
so is there any algorithm to detect this change something like it will give 100% to Column_A and 0% to Column_B

Comment: Hi! I recommend searching for articles about "feature selection". This is what this process is usually called.

Comment: Scikit-learn also has a submodule specifically for this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html